Generate CreateForm/EditForm dynamically for "args/options" from many CLI programs
I write code in node.js and typescript.
I have a REST backoffice front-end (build with react-admin but it doesn't matter) on which I need to develop a CRUD for CliOptionsEntity, which have this shape :
{ 
  configName: string // unique identifier
  name: string // the CLI package name
  options: string  // a json object with all args saved for this clie
}

I want to generate the FormCreate and FormEdit views dynamically (as opposite to create a new one each time I had a CLI), as I have many CLIs programs.
My CLI usually use yargs to have a generic interface for it's args. (I am OK to change if it helps.)
Usually, the CLI program is a function, which is just wrapped in my CLI interface.
What technical strategies can fit this use case so I can dynamically generate my form ?
